# Alternative way to flutter webview

Tags: flutter

How to display a piece of code in flutter application like image below
I tried to use `flutter_webview` package but i didn't like it.
I am asking if is there any alternative way i can use to display them

[image: hellow code]

Comment: Please, show us some of your flutter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show code in your flutter app you can use markdown and next package:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown